# Extracting Time from JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

I am calling my server code to return json data

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "myurl",
data: "{}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (appdata) {

        var testdata = $.parseJSON(appdata.d);

        console.log(testdata);

        $.each(testdata, function (index, appt) {
        //console.log(appt.PRODUCTID);// works fine
        //console.log(appt.ENTRYDATE);// works fine
        // var starttime=??
    }
});
```

Here is the `console.log(testdata)` output

```
[Object, Object]

0: Object

  PRODUCTID : "51",
  ENTRYDATE : "2013-02-13T12:30:00",
  CATEGORYID : null

__proto__:Object

1: Object

  PRODUCTID : "52",
  ENTRYDATE : "2013-02-13T12:40:00",
  CATEGORYID : null

__proto__: Object
  length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

How can I extract the time information from ENTRYDATE like (12:30) from the first object's entrydate `2013-02-13T12:30:00`

**Edit**

`console.log(appt.ENTRYDATE)` works fine, the issue only is how to extract time information from `appt.ENTRYDATE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`How can I extract the time information from ENTRYDATE like (12:30)`

to this: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4vsk/

```
$.each(testdata, function (index, appt) {
    var $getTime = appt.ENTRYDATE;// works fine
    var $Time = $getTime.substr($getTime.indexOf('T')+1).slice(0, -3);
    console.log($Time); // output will be: 12:30, 12:40
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the time information by using javascript split

```
 var datetime = appt.ENTRYDATE;
 var datedata = datetime.split("T");
 var datevalue = datedata[0]; //date value
 var timevalue = datedata[1]; //time value
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be the worst answer but you could try **split**

```
var starttime="2013-02-13T12:40:00";   // this comes from appt.ENTRYDATE 
var n=starttime.split("T"); 
console.log(n[1]);
```